# Suppose that $u, v, w, x \in \mathbb R^n$ s.t. $u+v+w+x = 0$. Prove that $(u+v).(u+x) = 0$ iff $\|u\|^2 + \|w\|^2 = \|v\|^2 + \|x\|^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $w \cdot w = \|v\|^2 + \|x\|^2 - \|u\|^2 + 2(u \cdot u + u \cdot v + u \cdot x + x \cdot v).$

Suppose $(u + v) \cdot (u + x) = 0$

Then

$u \cdot u + u \cdot v + u \cdot x + x \cdot v$

$= (u_1u_1 + \ldots + u_nu_n) + (u_1v+1 + \ldots + u_nv_n) + (u_1x_1 + \ldots + u_nx_n) + (x_1v_1 + \ldots + x_nv_n)$

$= u_1(u_1 + v_1) + \ldots + u_n(u_n + v_n) + x_1(u_1 + v_1) + \ldots + x_n(u_n + v_n)$

$= (u_1 + v_1) (u_1 + x_1) + (u_2 + v_2)(u_2 + x_2) + \ldots + (u_n + v_n)(u_n + x_n)$

$= (u + v) \cdot (u + x) = 0.$

That means $\|w\|^2 = \|v\|^2 + \|x\|^2 - \|u\|^2 + 2(\|u\|^2 + u \cdot v + u \cdot x + x \cdot v) = \|v\|^2 + \|x\|^2 - \|u\|^2$.

Supposing what's written above is correct, how do we prove the other direction. Been on it for a bit now - still nothing. Any hints. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like you somehow wrote a complicated proof that $(u+v)\cdot (u+x)=u\cdot u + u\cdot v+ u\cdot x + x\cdot v$ which just follows from bilinearity of inner products.

Comment: That part is a given hint in my textbook, so I had to use it. But because of the perpendicularity assumption, it works out. I think.

Comment: And the other direction follows from $2(u+v)\cdot(u+x)=||w||^2+||u||^2-||x||^2-||v||^2$

Comment: Couldn't possibly be simpler than that! I feel ridiculous now :) Thank you very much, user160738.